# Generate very very large random numbers

Tags: math, random, number-theory

How would you generate a very very large random number? I am thinking on the order of 2^10^9 (one billion bits). Any programming language -- I assume the solution would translate to other languages.

I would like a uniform distribution on [1,N].

My initial thoughts:

--You could randomly generate each digit and concatenate. Problem: even very good pseudorandom generators are likely to develop patterns with millions of digits, right?

- You could perhaps help create large random numbers by raising random numbers to random exponents. Problem: you must make the math work so that the resulting number is still random, and you should be able to compute it in a reasonable amount of time (say, an hour).
- If it helps, you could try to generate a possibly non-uniform distribution on a possibly smaller range (using the real numbers, for instance) and transform. Problem: this might be equally difficult.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which type are you going to store this in?

Comment: What do you need the number for?

Comment: Guess it'd have to be a string, or perhaps as pure binary data written to disk.... Open to suggestions!

Comment: Mainly just to try it/for fun. I'm in a number theory class where it could be useful. Certainly I don't have vital data hinging on the provable randomness of the number.

Comment: careful. "provably random" is a very tricky notion. any typical RNG won't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate `log2(N)` random bits to get a number `M`,
where `M` may be up to twice as large as `N`.
Repeat until `M` is in the range `[1;N]`.

Now to generate the random bits you could either use a source of true randomness, which is expensive.

Or you might use some cryptographically secure random number generator, for example AES with a random key encrypting a counter for subsequent blocks of bits. The cryptographically secure implies that there can be no noticeable patterns.

Comment: 2 questions.

1) Is there a simple proof that k random bits produce a random k-bit number? It seems intuitive, but....


2) Cryptographicly secure sounds good -- that means it's provably indistinguishable from random numbers, right? So you're suggesting, let k be a 128-bit random key, then for b=1 to log2(N)/128, use k to encrpyt b to some 128-bit number and concatenate that number. Yes?

Comment: I don't understand how would you use AES for generating random numbers. Are you implying that the ciphertext generated by AES has no noticeable patterns, and by this way, we could use it as a random number ?

Comment: This seems rather wasteful since in the worst case (*N* just over a power of two) you end up throwing away nearly half your attempts!

Comment: That's true, but it is a consequence of a pure bit-oriented approach. To mitigate the effect you could use a mixed approach and chop off some most significant bits (a machine word size would do). Run a generator that returns a suitable number for this part, and random bits for the LSB part, and the result will be usable by a high probability.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need the data for.  For most purposes, a PRNG is fast and simple.  But they are not perfect.  For instance I remember hearing that Monte Carlos simulations of chaotic systems are really good at revealing the underlying pattern in a PRNG.

If that is the sort of thing that you are doing, though, there is a simple trick I learned in grad school for generating lots of random data.  Take a large (preferably rapidly changing) file.  (Some big data structures from the running kernel are good.)  Compress it to increase the entropy.  Throw away the headers.  Then for good measure, encrypt the result.  If you're planning to use this for cryptographic purposes (and you didn't have a perfect entropy data set to work with), then reverse it and encrypt again.

The underlying theory is simple.  Information theory tells us that there is no difference between a signal with no redundancy and pure random data.  So if we pick a big file (ie lots of signal), remove redundancy with compression, and strip the headers, we have a pretty good random signal.  Encryption does a really good job at removing artifacts.  However encryption algorithms tend to work forward in blocks.  So if someone could, despite everything, guess what was happening at the start of the file, that data is more easily guessable.  But then reversing the file and encrypting again means that they would need to know the whole file, and our encryption, to find any pattern in the data.

The reason to pick a rapidly changing piece of data is that if you run out of data and want to generate more, you can go back to the same source again.  Even small changes will, after that process, turn into an essentially uncorrelated random data set.

Answer (score 1):

[NTL: A Library for doing Number Theory](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/)

This was recommended by my Coding Theory and Cryptography teacher... so I guess it does the work right, and it's pretty easy to use.

> RandomBnd, RandomBits, RandomLen -- routines for generating pseudo-random numbers

```
ZZ RandomLen_ZZ(long l);
// ZZ = psuedo-random number with precisely l bits,
// or 0 of l <= 0.
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't tell from the doc if it can do what I'm asking. Do you know?

Comment: I used it for implementing the RSA cipher... but I think I lost already the source code.. and it was way too long ago to remember what did I do there...

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the link -- could be really useful in general. But it looks like from the source that these won't work for very large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a random number generator that generates random numbers of X bits. And concatenated bits of [X1, X2, ... Xn ] create the number you want of N bits, as long as each X is random, I don't see why your large number wouldn't be random as well for all intents and purposes.  And if standard C rand() method is not secure enough, I'm sure there's plenty of other libraries (like the ones mentioned in this thread) whose pseudo-random numbers are "more random".

Answer (score 0):

> even very good pseudorandom generators are likely to develop patterns with millions of digits, right?

From [the wikipedia on pseudo-random number generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator):

A PRNG can be started from an arbitrary starting state using a seed state. It will always produce the same sequence thereafter when initialized with that state. The maximum length of the sequence before it begins to repeat is determined by the size of the state, measured in bits. However, since the length of the maximum period potentially doubles with each bit of 'state' added, it is easy to build PRNGs with periods long enough for many practical applications.

> You could perhaps help create large random numbers by raising random numbers to random exponents

I assume you're suggesting something like populating the values of a scientific notation with random values?

E.g.: `1.58901231 x 10^5819203489`

The problem with this is that your distribution is going to be logarithmic (or is that exponential? :) - same difference, it isn't even).  You will never get a value that has the millionth digit set, yet contains a digit in the one's column.

> you could try to generate a possibly non-uniform distribution on a possibly smaller range (using the real numbers, for instance) and transform

Not sure I understand this.  Sounds like the same thing as the exponential solution, with the same problems.  If you're talking about multiplying by a constant, then you'll get a lumpy distribution instead of a logarithmic (exponential?) one.

**Suggested Solution**

If you just need really big pseudo-random values, with a good distribution, use a PRNG algorithm with a larger state.  The Periodicity of a PRNG is often the square of the number of bits, so it doesn't take **that** many bits to fill even a really large number.

From there, you can use your first solution:

> You could randomly generate each digit and concatenate

Although I'd suggest that you use the full range of values returned by your PRNG (possibly 2^31 or 2^32), and populate a byte array with those values, splitting it up as necessary.  Otherwise you might be throwing away a lot of bits of randomness.  Also, scaling your values to a range (or using modulo) can easily screw up your distribution, so there's another reason to try to keep the max number of bits your PRNG can return.  Be careful to pack your byte array full of the bits returned, though, or you'll again introduce lumpiness to your distribution.

The problem with those solution, though, is how to fill that (larger than normal) seed state with random-enough values.  You might be able to use standard-size seeds (populated via time or GUID-style population), and populate your big-PRNG state with values from the smaller-PRNG.  This might work if it isn't mission critical how well distributed your numbers are.

If you need truly cryptographically secure random values, the only real way to do it is use a natural form of randomness, such as that at http://www.random.org/.  The disadvantages of natural randomness are availability, and the fact that many natural-random devices take a while to generate new entropy, so generating large amounts of data might be really slow.

You can also use a hybrid and be safe - natural-random seeds only (to avoid the slowness of generation), and PRNG for the rest of it.  Re-seed periodically.